# Obtener el contenido de un array u objeto PHP

Tags: php, phpexcel

Improvisé un código que lee los archivos *XML* de una carpeta, uno tras otro, y recupera la información de algunos campos determinados (título y resumen), y quiero pasar dicha información a un fichero *CSV* a una fila por fichero (una columna con títulos y otra con resúmenes).

Aquí está completo:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen("C:/*****/PHP/METADAT.csv","a"); 

$directorio = ('C:/Users/***/xml');

$ficheros1 = scandir($directorio);
$ficheros1 = array_diff($ficheros1,array('.','..')); 

$cantidad = count($ficheros1);

$i = 2;
while ($i <= $cantidad):

  $carga = simplexml_load_file('C:/Users/***/xml');
  /*acceder a las rutas XML que nos interesan (XPATH)*/
  $titulo = $carga->xpath(
    '/MD_Metadata/identificationInfo/MD_DataIdentification/citation/CI_Citation/title'
  );
  $resumen = $carga->xpath('/MD_Metadata/identificationInfo/MD_DataIdentification/abstract');

  /*volcar el contenido en CSV*/

  $lista[$i] = array($titulo,$resumen);
  $i++;
endwhile;        //fin del bucle while

foreach ($lista as &$campos) {
  fputcsv($fp, $campos);
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

El problema es que el `fputcsv($fp,$campos)` me crea un *CSV* que contiene la palabra *Array* muchas veces, porque al hacer la carga de datos en `$titulo` y `$resumen` los considera objetos `SimpleXMLObject` o algo así que en su interior tienen la información deseada, cuando yo realmente sólo quiero el valor textual contenido en 'title' y 'abstract' de dentro de mis *XML*.

¿Puedo recuperar ese valor de algún modo sencillo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

primero, `xpath` [retorna un array](http://php.net/manual/es/simplexmlelement.xpath.php), por lo que debes tomar alguno de esos elementos. Si tienes, exactamente 1, basta con leer la posicion `[0]`. Luego, debes hacer un casting de `SimpleXMLObject` a `string`. Algo así como:

```
$titulo = (string)$carga->xpath('/MD_Metadata/identificationInfo/MD_DataIdentification/citation/CI_Citation/title')[0];
$resumen = (string)$carga->xpath('/MD_Metadata/identificationInfo/MD_DataIdentification/abstract')[0];
```

espero ayudarte!
saludos

Comment: que grande, basandome en lo que decias modifique este trozo:        "$titulo = $carga->xpath('/MD_Metadata/identificationInfo/MD_DataIdentification/citation/CI_Citation/title');
        $resumen = $carga->xpath('/MD_Metadata/identificationInfo/MD_DataIdentification/abstract');                                                                                                                   
        $titulo = (string)$titulo[0];
        $resumen = (string)$resumen[0];"               Y todo corre perfecto, gracias

Comment: no olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta :)